# PayPal test credit card stopped working in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created a test VISA card number several months ago and I was able to use it during development (via FoxyCart).

I've tried the same number again today and this time I received the following error message:

`Error: There was an error processing your payment: (10626 Risk) Transaction refused due to risk model`

Has something changed in the way Paypal is handling sandbox accounts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error code 10626 seems to be risk model decline. It may happen due to risk settings at merchant account. Please contact PayPal MTS at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com and provide more information for checking further.